# Write twitterAPI pagination to file

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code that is searching twitter.  I'm trying to write the results to a file.   The TwitterRestPager is running every 30 seconds.   I want to cut this off after 10 minutes i.e. close the file and end the script.

When I run the code I get an error : Type error: Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str'

I need to write each item to a new line and quit searching after 10 minutes.  Any ideas?

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
from TwitterAPI import TwitterRestPager

api = TwitterAPI("blah", "blah", "blah", "blah")

pager = TwitterRestPager(api, 'search/tweets', {'q':'deflation', 'count':100,'exclude_replies':'TRUE'})

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in pager.get_iterator(wait=30):
        if 'text' in item:
            f.write(item['id'] + '\n' + item['created_at'].encode('utf-8', 'replace') +'\n' + item['text'].encode('utf-8', 'replace') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to concatenate `item['id']`, which is an `int`, to `\n`. You must first cast the `int` to a string using `str(item['id'])`.

For your second question -- how to quit after 10 minutes -- look up `time.clock()`. You can use this function in your `for` loop to test when 10 minutes has passed.